# how to secure dll methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, security, assemblies

I have a class for encryption and decryption of Password from database. I have a secret key in config and a salt in my code.

If someone get access to dll and database then he can decrypt my data by importing dll to his application.

Is there something to protect calling method outside of dll

Comment: You must **hash** your passwords.  This way, it will be impossible to decrypt them.

Comment: Your attacker can simply decompile the DLL and extract the key.  You should store the key in a secure storage location in the environment.

Comment: @SLaks you cannot generally send a hash of the password to the database in order to authenticate.

Comment: @StefanH, as question stands now to me it does not look like OP tries to encrypt connection string for that DB, but rather stores some secret information (Passwords) in the DB. Also after re-reading question your interpretation is possible too.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - You are right, the precise workflow that the OP is using is not as clear as I first thought.  I definitely agree with SLaks in that if there are passwords being stored that are not needed to authenticate the app, then they should be hashed, not stored in an encrypted state.  I defiitely read the question as the OP was concerned about storing the credentials for initiating the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you shouldn't store passwords within your code, as decompilation is fairly easy.

The best option is to store this information in a secure location, and ideally only store hashes of the information.

That being said, there are various options you can do to help protect yourself.

One option is obfuscation, but this still only makes it more difficult, but not impossible, to discover your information.  Some obfuscators are better than others, and will "break" most decompilation tools.  That being said, as long as the computer can figure it out, a talented individual can as well.

Answer (score 2):

I heartily recommend using the DPAPI for encrypting your app or web.config.  It will help to ensure that the only way to decrypt that config is by doing so in your environment, simple file access is not enough.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx